# How can I find similar documents in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have food db listing similar to:

```
 {
   Name: "burger",
   ingredients: [
     {Item:"bread"},
     {Item:"cheese"},
     {Item:"tomato"}
   ]
 }
```

How can I find documents that have the most similar items in `ingredients`?

Comment: probably you mean similar documents ?

Comment: Yes i meant document's

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, your data should be remodelled as below:

```
{
  name: "Burger",
  ingredients: [
    "bread",
    "cheese",
    "tomato",
    "beef"
  ]
}
```

The extra "Item" does not add any additional information nor does it help accessing the data in any way.

Next, you need to create a [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/). The docs state that

> `text` indexes can include any field whose value is a string or an array of string elements.

So we simply do a

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"ingredients":"text"})
```

Now we can do a [`$text` search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text):

```
db.collection.find(
  { $text: { $search: "bread beef" } },
  { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
```

which should give you the most relevant documents.

However, what you could also do is a non-text search for direct matches:

```
db.collection.find({ingredients:"beef"})
```

or for multiple ingredients

```
db.collections.find({ ingredients: { $all: ["beef","bread"] } })
```

So for searching by user input, you can use the text search and for search by selected ingredients, you can use the non-text search.

Answer (score -2):

your best chance is if you store ingredients in a text field i.e:
{ingredients : "bread cheese tomato"} then you have to use a [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) and  query for similarity db.your_collection.find({$text: {[$search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/): {"tomato" }}, {score: { $meta: "textScore" }}).sort({score: {$meta: "textScore" } } ) and get most relevant documents

Comment: I think creating a text field for the ingredients is not optimal. It makes the ingredients more complicated to manage, for example in aggregations (think of a list of all ingredients you want to aggregate) or for single matches, let alone `$push`. Remember that you can also text index an array. See my answer for details.